# Правильно ли стоят знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Верна ли пунктуация: «Повышение роли управляющих предприятием по сравнению с ролью собственников происходит последовательно в мировой экономике, начиная с XIX века»?

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что в этом предложении не нужны знаки препинания. По поводу оборота "начиная с": он действительно может вызывать вопрос и в разных ситуациях отделяться запятой или не отделяться. Вот что пишет по данному вопросу [ГРАМОТА.РУ](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_457):

*Обороты с предлогом «начиная с» обычно имеют значение уточнения или пояснения и поэтому выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми).
...
Однако если оборот тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым и не является уточняющим, то обособление не требуется.*

Answer (score 0):

**1. ПО СРАВНЕНИЮ С (кем, чем), *предлог***
***Обычно обособляются*** обороты с предлогом **по сравнению**, которые располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым.
*"Повышение"* - подлежащее, *"происходит"* - сказуемое, к тому же само предложение довольно-таки длинное. Вывод: обособляем оборот запятыми(возможно и тире).
[**Пунктуация при оборотах**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

**2. НАЧИНАЯ С (чего), *предлог***
***Обособление не требуется,*** если предлог «начиная с» в буквальном смысле указывает на время, дату начала чего-либо (при этом слово «начиная» обычно можно опустить).
Вывод: не обособляем.
[**начиная с**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_457)

Пунктуация в предложении будет такой:
***Повышение роли управляющих предприятием, по сравнению с ролью собственников, происходит последовательно в мировой экономике начиная с XIX века.***